# Can't open Jupyter Notebooks in VS Code

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I am using anaconda installation of python and have installed VS code on my machine. For some reason I can't open Jupyter notebooks on my vscode most of the time. Sometime they open without any error and most of the time it just says 'Python extension loading'. I have already installed python 2020 extension from market place in VS Code to do data science related work and have selected conda installation in commandPalate>SelectPythonToStartJupyterServer but no luck. I am not sure what causes the notebooks to open sometimes as I can't pinpoint the cause of them being not opening.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Try to open it on the browser. If it works, then the problem in the extension.

Comment: All the notebooks open properly on the browser. I did search on the internet and in youtube videos other people didn't had the same issue. Is there a way to fix it.

Comment: I never used Jupyter with VScode so I can't be sure. You may try another extension. Also, try to report the error to the extension developer.